# Soundmanager: MySound is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, soundmanager2

```
            soundManager.url = 'swf/';

            soundManager.createSound({
                id: 'mySound',
                url: 'http://localhost/htmlshooter/mp3/gun.mp3',
                autoLoad: true,
                autoPlay: true,
                volume: 100
            });

            function placeimage(){
                var t = $('<img src="img/php/target.png" alt="image" id="' +  Math.floor(Math.random()*55)  + '" onclick="doclickimg(this.id);">');
                $('#div').append(t);
                t.css('left', Math.floor(Math.random()*(800 - t.width())));
                t.css('top', Math.floor(Math.random()*(300 - t.height())));
                setTimeout(placeimage, 2000);
            }

            placeimage();

            function doclickimg(imgid){
                doclickdiv();
                $('#'+imgid).remove();
                // +1 score
            }


            function doclickdiv() {
                mySound.play(); 
                // -1 bullet
            }
```

Now when i click on my div, the image won't disappear, and it says that MySound, from MySound.play in doclickdiv() isn't defined.

Please help me! Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are receiving this error because `mySound` isn't a defined object yet. You'll probably have better luck with...

```
var mySound = soundManager.createSound({
    id: 'mySound',
    url: 'http://localhost/htmlshooter/mp3/gun.mp3',
    autoLoad: true,
    autoPlay: true,
    volume: 100
});
```

or...

```
function doclickdiv() {
    soundManager.getSoundById('mySound').play(); 
    // -1 bullet
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`mySound` is not defined.  You *probably* want to change:

```
soundManager.createSound({
            id: 'mySound',
            url: 'http://localhost/htmlshooter/mp3/gun.mp3',
            autoLoad: true,
            autoPlay: true,
            volume: 100
        });
```

to

```
var mySound = soundManager.createSound({
            id: 'mySound',
            url: 'http://localhost/htmlshooter/mp3/gun.mp3',
            autoLoad: true,
            autoPlay: true,
            volume: 100
        });
```